# How to disable Kotlin compiler in IntelliJ IDEA for Maven Java projects?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a Java only multi module Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA and I can see IDEA calling a Kotlin compiler whenever I rebuild a module or choose to run all tests. This is shown in the background processes bar. It sometimes shows `Kotlin: connecting to daemon` as well which seems to take quite some time.
Is there a way to tell IDEA to ignore Kotlin completely for a certain project? I guess the build times could speed up a little bit that way. I know I can disable the Kotlin plugin but that's not what I want as it would be disabled for all projects.

Comment: I don't know how it works, but I would speculate that the Kotlin compiler is mostly there to facilitate the building of the project and assembling the project. Since there isn't actually any Kotlin in your project, it likely just hands the task over to the project JDK. I don't think you need to worry about performance in this case. If you think the project might have been miss-classified as a Kotlin project, this link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497454/intellij-idea-ultimate-2018-3-thinks-my-java-9-project-is-a-kotlin-project

Comment: This is a problem with IDEA builder. I created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36705. A workaround is to disable the Kotlin IDEA plugin.

Comment: Can someone make @AlexeyBelkov post an answer please?

Comment: @HansWurst By the way, I forgot to ask you. Does it help to enable "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven"? This should circumvent the built-in IDEA builder, so Kotlin compiler may not be activated. If this doesn't help, I have no other ideas.

Comment: That might help but leads to other problems. On top of my head I remember not being able to execute single test methods then by right clicking on them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to disable the plugin of Kotlin, and restart IDEA, and it is solved, even I continue using Gradle. Community 2019.3.

Answer (score -1):

Intellij provides 2 different settings. Project wise setting and global settings.

You can see the project specific settings by "right click the project" and select "Open Module Settings" as Below -

[image: Module Settings]

This will open `Project Settings` window. You can select kotlin and remove there in the below screen.

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: I thought this fixed the problem but after removing the Kotlin SDK I still get the Kotlin compiler output in the background processes bar

Comment: I never had Kotlin configured in my project and never downloaded SDK. Still I see IDEA connecting to daemon on every build.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Maven` for build manager, you might be using `Koltin` plugin to build the project.

The plugin name is `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin`.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>jpa</plugin>
          </compilerPlugins>
          <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

You just need to delete it!

Comment: Thank you but I don't have that plugin in my maven pom.xml

Comment: Would you like to update your `pom.xml` to your question?